# a question on `exec` parameter in .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, deepin

I have installed Zotero with .tarball as suggested [here](https://www.zotero.org/support/installation), and the following is what I encountered:

1. I can launch zotero in terminal with `/opt/zotero/zotero`
2. I **cannot** launch zotero by clicking on the default `.desktop` file, where the `exec` parameter is configured as `bash -c "$(dirname $(realpath $(echo %k | sed -e 's/^file:\/\///')))/zotero -url %U"`
3. I can launch zotero in terminal with `bash -c "$(dirname $(realpath $(echo %k | sed -e 's/^file:\/\///')))/zotero -url %U"`
4. I can launch zotero by clicking the `.desktop` file where I reconfigure the `exec` parameter to `bash -c /opt/zotero/zotero`

I don't know why the second one doesn't work. Is it the problem due to an application level, desktop environment level or something else?

BTW, I'm using the `deepin v20.8` distribution.

Comment: I got the same problem, worked around it by removing the tarball installation and using the wrapper from https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb instead.

Comment: Option 4 seems like the obviously best choice.  even better, unless /opt/zotero/zotero is a bash script without the execute bits set, you can make it even shorter and get rid of the `bash -c`.   And even if it isn't executable, you can make it so with `chmod a+x /opt/zotero/zotero`.   Maybe also add the `-url "%U"` args back to the exec command line.

Comment: (3) doesn't add anything meaningful - What are `%k` and `%U` in that case?

Comment: @muru I run that command in `/opt/zotero` directory, just to make sure the default setting by Zotero means something reasonable (kind of experiment), I don't understand this whole bunch of things in fact...